# .NET 7 API Controller Accept and Return Audio File as Stream

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that converts audio file's format to desired **Wav** format. These module's methods are accepting audio files as `Stream` and returning `MemoryStream` as result.  I need to create a controller which takes audio files as stream and also returning it as a stream body content to user. This is my controller, but I couldn't find a solution that fits my requirements. How can I achieve this?

```
public class AudioController : ControllerBase
 {
     private readonly ILogger<AudioController> _logger;

     public AudioController(ILogger<AudioController> logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;

     }

     [HttpPost]
     [Route("/opus-to-wav")]
     public async Task<IActionResult> ConvertOpusToWav()
     {

         MemoryStream wavFile = WavConverter.ConvertOpusToWav(stream);


         return Ok(wavFile);
     }


     [HttpPost]
     [Route("/aac-to-wav")]
     public async Task<IActionResult> ConvertAACToWav()
     {
         MemoryStream wavFile = WavConverter.ConvertAACToWav(stream);


         return Ok(wavFile);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get and return stream. Don't know why but you need to copy body of the request to another `MemoryStream`.

```
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("/stream-aac-to-wav")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> ConvertStreamToWav()
  {
      using MemoryStream aacFile = new MemoryStream();

      await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(aacFile);

      aacFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

      using MemoryStream wavFile = WavConverter.ConvertAACToWav(aacFile);
    
      byte[] wavArray = wavFile.ToArray();

      return File(wavArray, "audio/wav", "convertedAudio.wav");
  }
```